# Why doesn't this OpenGL program draw a triangle?

Tags: opengl, go, shader, glfw

I am trying to learn modern OpenGL and want to draw a triangle like this: [image: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/red_triangle.png]

I am following this tutorial: [www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/), but all I get is the dark blue background (clear color). What could be wrong with this code?

I am writing this in Go and tried to run it on Ubuntu and OS X.
Note: I am using the glfw 3 library instead of glfw 2.7 that is used in the tutorial.

I think the relevant parts are:

```
func setup() {
    gl.ClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0)

    makeProgram(vertexShaderSource,fragmentShaderSource)

    vertexBufferData := []float32{
        -1,-1,0,
         1,-1,0,
         0, 1,0,
    }

    vertexBuffer = gl.GenBuffer()
    vertexBuffer.Bind(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER)
    gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(vertexBufferData)*4, vertexBufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}

func draw() {
    gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    program.Use()
    // first attribute buffer: vertices
    var vertexAttrib = program.GetAttribLocation("vertexPosition_modelspace")
    vertexAttrib.EnableArray()
    vertexBuffer.Bind(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var f float32 = 0.0

    vertexAttrib.AttribPointer(
        3,     // size
        gl.FLOAT, // type
        false, // normalized
        0,     // stride
        &f) // array buffer offset

    // draw the triangle
    gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

    vertexAttrib.DisableArray()

}
```

Link to the full code: https://gist.github.com/mbertschler/8672365

I already tried to debug this with OpenGL Profiler on OSX, but it shows me no errors so far.

Comment: Don't post links to code on external sites. If you think your code would be too large otherwise, _make it shorter_.

Comment: The last argument to `vertexAttrib.AttribPointer()` is different to the tutorial you're following.  In the tutorial, it passes `0` cast as a `void *` pointer.  Here, you've passed the address of a `float32` variable (which won't be zero).  Could that be the problem?

Comment: `&f) // array buffer offset` doesn't make any sense. It should be an offset, in bytes - cast to `(void *)` - into the currently bound GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. Try replacing `&f` with `(0)`.

Comment: @BrettHale putting in `(0)` compiles but outputs: `panic: type must be a pointer, a slice, uintptr or nil.` As far as I understand (0) is just a integer literal. What does (void*)0 mean exactly, I can't find a clear description. Is it a pointer to a value of `0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in:

```
var f float32 = 0.0

vertexAttrib.AttribPointer(
    3,     // size
    gl.FLOAT, // type
    false, // normalized
    0,     // stride
    &f) // array buffer offset
```

Although it seemed to work for the OP of this question:
[OpenGL Vertex Buffer doesn't draw anything in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284055/opengl-vertex-buffer-doesnt-draw-anything-in-golang) it doesn't with my program. The accepted answer had the right version of this call. It works with `nil` as array buffer offset.

### Working Code:

(At least for `github.com/go-gl/gl` bindings)

```
vertexAttrib.AttribPointer(
    3,     // size
    gl.FLOAT, // type
    false, // normalized
    0,     // stride
    nil) // array buffer offset
```