# Go Lang OpenGL simple shape - blank screen

Tags: opengl, go, sdl-2, opengl-3, glew

I need some assistance into why this piece of code produces a blank green window.  I made this by combining examples from https://github.com/Jragonmiris/mathgl/blob/master/examples/opengl-tutorial/tutorial02/main.go and https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/blob/master/examples/opengl3.go.  I guess i'm not sure if this is a bug with the GoLang sdl/gl framework or an issue with my OpenGL understanding.  All this should draw is a cube.

My code is:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    // gl "github.com/chsc/gogl/gl33"
    "github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl"
    // "math"
    "github.com/Jragonmiris/mathgl"
    "github.com/go-gl/gl"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

// var program gl.Program = 0
// var buffer gl.Buffer = 0

func MakeProgram(vert, frag string) gl.Program {

    vertShader, fragShader := gl.CreateShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER), gl.CreateShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    vertShader.Source(vert)
    fragShader.Source(frag)

    vertShader.Compile()
    fragShader.Compile()

    prog := gl.CreateProgram()

    prog.AttachShader(vertShader)
    prog.AttachShader(fragShader)
    prog.Link()
    prog.Validate()
    fmt.Println(prog.GetInfoLog())

    return prog
}

func main() {
    var window *sdl.Window
    var context sdl.GLContext
    var event sdl.Event
    var running bool
    var err error

    runtime.LockOSThread()

    if 0 != sdl.Init(sdl.INIT_EVERYTHING) {
        panic(sdl.GetError())
    }
    window, err = sdl.CreateWindow(winTitle, sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        winWidth, winHeight, sdl.WINDOW_OPENGL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if window == nil {
        panic(sdl.GetError())
    }
    context = sdl.GL_CreateContext(window)
    if context == nil {
        panic(sdl.GetError())
    }

    if gl.Init() != 0 {
        panic("gl error")
    }

    gl.ClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, .5)
    gl.Viewport(0, 0, winWidth, winHeight)

    program := MakeProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource)
    defer program.Delete()

    matrixID := program.GetUniformLocation("MVP")
    Projection := mathgl.Perspective(45.0, 4.0/3.0, 0.1, 100.0)
    View := mathgl.LookAt(4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    Model := mathgl.Ident4f()
    MVP := Projection.Mul4(View).Mul4(Model) 

    gl.Enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
    gl.DepthFunc(gl.LESS)
    gl.Enable(gl.BLEND)
    gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

    vertexArray := gl.GenVertexArray()
    defer vertexArray.Delete()
    vertexArray.Bind()

    buffer := gl.GenBuffer()
    defer buffer.Delete()
    buffer.Bind(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER)
    gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(triangle_vertices)*4, &triangle_vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    running = true
    for running {
        for event = sdl.PollEvent(); event != nil; event = sdl.PollEvent() {
            switch t := event.(type) {
            case *sdl.QuitEvent:
                running = false
            case *sdl.MouseMotionEvent:

                fmt.Printf(string(t.Timestamp))
            }
        }

        gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) // | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        program.Use()
        matrixID.UniformMatrix4fv(false, MVP)
        attribLoc := gl.AttribLocation(0)
        attribLoc.EnableArray()
        buffer.Bind(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER)
        attribLoc.AttribPointer(3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, nil)

        gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

        attribLoc.DisableArray()

        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)

        sdl.GL_SwapWindow(window)
    }

    sdl.GL_DeleteContext(context)
    window.Destroy()
    sdl.Quit()
}



const (
    winTitle           = "OpenGL Shader"
    winWidth           = 640
    winHeight          = 480
    vertexShaderSource = `
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;
void main(){

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4 (vertexPosition_modelspace,1.0);

}
`
    fragmentShaderSource = `
#version 330 core

// Ouput data
out vec3 color;

void main()
{

    // Output color = red 
    color = vec3(1,0,0);

}
`
)

var triangle_vertices = []float32{
    -.5, -.5, -.5,
    .5, -.5, -.5,
    0.0, 0.5, -.5,
}
```

So I'm still having trouble drawing a simple shape on the screen. I made a few changes such as simplifying my shape (a triangle).  I created coordinates so they would be more towards the -z axis so I would be able to see them but that has not worked.  I then set the MVP matrix (moving the camera back some) just to make sure.  My shaders are simple as I am only passing in a vec3 vertex position and mat4 MVP matrix so believe shaders are working correctly? Sorry for all the confusion, i think i maybe missing something here.

Update:
I also ran the version commands for opengl:

```
fmt.Println(gl.GetString(gl.VERSION))
fmt.Println(gl.GetString(gl.VENDOR))
fmt.Println(gl.GetString(gl.RENDERER))
```

for which the output was:

4.5.0 NVIDIA 347.09
NVIDIA Corporation
GeForce GTX 650 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

Not sure if this has any impact?

Update:
I have looked at some more examples and decided to try and add some sdl attributes but still no luck:

```
sdl.GL_SetAttribute(sdl.GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1)
sdl.GL_SetAttribute(sdl.GL_RED_SIZE, 8)
sdl.GL_SetAttribute(sdl.GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8)
sdl.GL_SetAttribute(sdl.GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8)
sdl.GL_SetAttribute(sdl.GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8)
```

Update:

I modified this post to just include more recent code to not scare people away from TLDR.

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think this might be rendering it with you inside the cube, so you're not seeing the faces because the winding is wrong from that perspective.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm using pretty small values (1.0, 0 , etc).  The sdl2 link example cube seems to work fine, i'm able to see everything in that example. The only change I made was to the shaders with much simpler shaders from the tutorial2 link

Comment: Note that the shaders in the second tutorial you linked move the cube. You're rendering so the vertex elements are at 1.0 or -1.0, but you're at (0,0,0) -- you're inside the cube. In OpenGL faces are oriented based on clockwise-ness. Presumably, your vertices are oriented clockwise with respect to the OUTSIDE of the cube, so you don't see them because you're viewing the triangles from the "back", where they're invisible.

Comment: Note that this example is basically mathgl tutorial 4 (these are mine, though they're adapted from a C tutorial), but with SDL instead of glfw.

Comment: just a silly suggestion but what is the log output from shader compilation? are you sure your source text is including the enter codes when defined as you have now? if not then your `//` rems are till end of source code ...

Comment: Non-compiling shaders generally act as passthrough shaders with no vertex transformations and Gl-default-gray vertex coloring, so if that was the only problem he'd likely see the cube, except gray instead of red.

Comment: Yea the shaders compile and link ok without error. I think @Jsor is correct about MVP - i'm stuck "inside" the cube. I'm going to update this post once I get this thing to compile again

Comment: So I still wasn't able to get things working I changed bunch of things for testing but no luck.  Posted new code above.  Can anyone provide some comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what my problem was in this code.

The first thing I had to do was

```
positionAttrib := program.GetAttribLocation("vertexPosition_modelspace")
```

for all the input variables going into the vertex shader. This was done after binding the VBO for each array.

Next,

If you notice my code above:

```
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(triangle_vertices)*4, &triangle_vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

I simply replaced it with triangle_vertices array, and not the address:

```
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(triangle_vertices)*4, triangle_vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

Doing this seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment, but I do not yet have enough reputation.

The solution already provided *nearly* solved my similar issue, however not quite.

Where the provided solution was

```
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(triangle_vertices)*4, triangle_vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

The actual code which solved my issue is

```
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(triangle_vertices)*4, gl.Ptr(triangle_vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

I have also answered a similar question with this, but in more detail, which can be found here:
[OpenGL Vertex Buffer doesn't draw anything in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284055/opengl-vertex-buffer-doesnt-draw-anything-in-golang/33408359#33408359)